# How get data with angular from the backend and send it with node.js for the frontend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm changing my node.js application, i was using EJS template engine and now i want use angular.

For this i already install angular and is working good, but now i want get my data, and for this i'm using the $http service:

```
(function($) {
  app.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.data;

    $http.get('/data').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;

      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;

      });

  }]);

}(jQuery));
```

And i'm sending the data in the backend:

```
  restAPI.GET(options).then(function (result) {
    res.render('data/index.html', {
      event: result,
    });
  }).then(undefined, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

But its returning the HTML from the same page that i'm using the controller. What am i doing wrong here??

What is returning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html ng-app="app"> <head> <title> Testando Angular </title> </head> <body> <div ng-controller="EventCtrl"> {{data}} </div> </body> <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="/controllers/EventCtrl.js"></script> </html>
```

Comment: Your telling node to send a file.  Aren't you wanting to send data?

Comment: but how can i load the HTML and still send the data??

Comment: You'll have to describe specifically what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Node should serve up the html file angular runs on.  Then you have to create an API that sends angular whatever data it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have node serve up the page which angular lives on. 
(This is using just an example using express)
Something like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('../public/index.html');
    res.end();
});
```

Then you need to set up routes for angular to query so it can get data:

```
app.get('/api/data', function (req, res) {
        //Get some data here however you do that
    res.json(data) //Send your data back to angular in the callback of your database query ( or whatever you are doing )
    }
```

You use `res.render()` to send a page.  You don't want to send a page.  You just want to send data if you are using the $http.get request shown above.  Fetch your data and send it with `res.json(data)`

If you need some insight into how all the pieces fit together, I would recommend working through the following tutorial:
[Setting Up a MEAN Stack SPA](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application)